# Error when directly visit lazy loaded module children route in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvmi8t

I have this lazy loaded module for a sub route using `loadChildren` in the base app module and the children routes of this lazy loaded module are dynamically setup when this module is being constructed:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([]), CommonModule],
  declarations: [LazyComponent, TestComponent, DefaultComponent],
  entryComponents: [LazyComponent, TestComponent, DefaultComponent]
})
export class LazyModule {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    const config: Route = router.config.find(r => r.path === 'lazypage');
    if (config) {
      config.children = [
        {
          path: '', component: LazyComponent, children: [
            {
              path: 'itemA', children: [
                { path: 'item1', component: TestComponent },
                { path: 'item2', component: TestComponent },
                { path: '', component: DefaultComponent }
              ]
            },
            {
              path: 'itemB', children: [
                { path: 'item1', component: TestComponent },
                { path: 'item2', component: TestComponent },
                { path: '', component: DefaultComponent }
              ]
            },
            {
              path: 'itemC', children: [
                { path: 'item1', component: TestComponent },
                { path: '', component: DefaultComponent }
              ]
            },
            {
              path: '', component: DefaultComponent
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
    }
  }

}
```

It works fine if I visit the sub route that loads this lazy loaded module first and then subsequently visit one of the children routes. But exception thrown when I first directly visit one of the children routes (via direct URL input). I wonder why and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: deep linking requuires server-side url rewrites

Comment: @pixelbits thanks, but a lazy loaded module of non-dynamic children routes work even when deep linking, so I wonder why the dynamic part caused this.

Comment: If you change routeLink to `routerLink="/lazypage/itemA/item1"` then you will see that it works the same as if you visit url directly. It means only one: angular router get's routes from `module.injector.get(ROUTES)` for lazy loaded module(https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4648597d14e843f75c5e9dd761af740c1c27b5c0/packages/router/src/router_config_loader.ts#L42) and it can't get dynamic routes you defined in constructor. It will only available after subsequently visit on of suchildren

Comment: @yurzui thank you I understand that, if you look at my updated example I already demoed what you said. Angular is not picking up the dynamic routes until next visit, seems like a bug to me. Do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: It's not a bug. You should declare routes in a declarative way